# Seeking open source tool for 3D Interpolation

Tags: software-recommendations, interpolation, 3d, open-source-gis, kriging

[Empirical Bayesian Kriging 3D (EBK3D)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geostatistical-analyst/empirical-bayesian-kriging-3d.htm) looks to be the tool I need within ArcGIS.  It requires a GeoStatistical Analyst license.

*Is there is a similar tool or library that is free and open source?*

I'm open to creative solutions, but I'm not finding much that is promising.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at SAGA GIS (System for Automated Geoscientific Analyses). If you install QGIS 3.10 it will automatically install SAGA GIS as an integrated processing tool. Saga GIS comes with a couple of Kriging methods.

[image]

I have no seen the term Empirical Bayesian Kriging but you might find something that might be of interest.

In addition, there is another tool called GeoR that has the Bayesan method:

***(Full documentation is available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoR/geoR.pdf)***

[image]

Please take a look at this thread on researchgate, https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_software_packages_for_geostatistical_analysis they are asking about the available Geostatistical packages and some listed are open source. But it all goes back to "R" from what I read.

I hope this helps.